# Counting date elements in R: Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R, very basic which contains one column of soley dates. for this example I have elements as

2018-01-01

2018-01-01

2018-01-01

2018-01-02

2018-01-03

The issue is when I plot this data frame, the "date" is plotted on the Y axis as oppose to the X.

I believe if I add another column where, for every date I count the occurrences

dates$count <- ...

so I end up with a new data frame:

Date          Count

2018-01-01    3

2018-01-02    1

2018-01-03    1

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to plot a bar plot of counts per date?

Comment: trying to plot dates on the X axis, and the a count of each date on the Y, it can be any graph type, line or bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're hoping for?

```
dates<-data.frame(Date=c("2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-01-03"))

plot( dates$Date )
```

[image: output plot]

If so, your column is probably in `Date` format, you may want to convert it to `factor` for plotting. You can do this with:

```
plot( factor( dates$Date ) )
```

Comment: hmm.. yes this seems to work. For some reason, with my current data frame which has 58000 dates assigned, I do not get the same axis layout

Comment: Did you try the `factor` conversion I mentioned at the end of my answer?

Comment: @JRH31, then you should consider *accepting* the answer. Thanks.